# Can 10Base-T1L / 10Base-T1S Ethernet be used in a bus topology?

Tags: ethernet, bus, topology

Old 10mbit standards like 10Base2 (thinnet) and 10Base5 (thicknet) are used in a bus topology, multiple devices are connected to one continous cable (or with BNC T-connectors, but same principle).

Is the same true for the new "single pair ethernet" standards 10Base-T1L and 10Base-T1S? Can these be used in a bus topology as well or do they require a star topology like most other PHYs today?

Comment: What does your research indicate?

Comment: @Justme to be honest, I don't know. I found little information about these standards since they're rather new and not widespread.

Comment: Yes and Yes ...both are bus connections over typically twisted pair wiring..

Comment: @JackCreasey Hi Jack, thanks for the answer. Can you share your source?

Comment: @Zciurus-Alt-Del Read the specifications.

Comment: 10BASE-T1L cannot be used in a bus network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10BASE-T1S can be used in a bus network (mixing segment) with up to at least 8 nodes and up to at least 25m. A Physical Layer Collision Avoidance Algorithm (PLCA) is also used in conjunction with the traditional CSMA/CD medium access control to avoid collisions and allow up to 95% network utilization.

10BASE-T1L supports only point-to-point link segments, but up to 1000m.

Source: IEEE 802.3cg-2019 Clauses 146 (10BASE-T1L), 147 (10BASE-T1S), and 148 (Physical Layer Collision Avoidance).